# Making an offline azure VM backup?

Tags: backup, azure

I'm fairly new to Azure, I've a VM running that I'd like to archive and possibly restore later, but I'd prefer to download the backup file and store it for myself offline, rather than pay for storage to hold the backup in the azure cloud.

Is this possible with azure?

Comment: Have you reviewed the Microsoft Docs [man page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-backup-import-export) for Azure backups?

Comment: @JW0914 haha, I put in my question that I'd "read the docs but got lost in the jargon", and a mod asked me to edit that bit out. I'm a coder, not a devOps guys, I don't even know if what I want to do is possible, so thought i'd ask here.

Comment: @JW0914 and yeah i found that page. "Backup" in azure jargon means a scheduled task, in the colloquial way i am using it, it means "stop copy destroy", and maybe later "copy start". I'm trying to be able to store a VM i no longer wish to pay for, and not pay for that storage, and then restore it later

Comment: For the edit you were asked to make, in the future, a better wording might be _"I read the following Microsoft Docs:"_ or _"I read the following man page(s)"_, etc.  I'm not sure why a moderator would have requested that to be removed, as it only would need to be made more specific since that is a critical piece of information.  I've never used the Azure platform before and since Microsoft revamped their man pages [Microsoft Docs] to be vastly more helpful than they used to be, that's always my first stop.  If Azure offers free tech support, have you tried reaching out to them?